# plot panel data with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

This is very likely a very simple problem.. I have a panel data like this (the America baby names data):

```
    Year    Name    Count
0   1960    Betty   6503
1   1960    Thelma  838
2   1961    Betty   5578
3   1961    Thelma  773
4   1962    Betty   4766
5   1962    Thelma  750
...
```

I just want to plot the time trend for each name, can I do this with `seaborn`? I thought I can use the `tsplot()` in `seaborn`, but it seems this function is not for what I'm after. And also I didn't see any documentation for this function, only an API.

I can do this with `matplotlib` (using `pandas`）:

```
grouped = data.groupby('Name')
for key, group in grouped:
    plt.plot(group.Year, group.Count, label=key)
plt.legend();
```

but I'm learning `seaborn` now, so I wonder if there is some way to do it in `seaborn`.

Comment: I can't say exactly why your question was downvoted, however my guess is that it's in part because they're is no indication of what type of plot, or what you would like the final output to look like. Also is there something about seaborn that you need? Here is the link for the `tsplot()` [documentation](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.tsplot.html)

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your reply. Me myself also have no idea why it's downvoted. I said I want the time trend for each name in my data, and I've given the data and the code to replicate what the plot would look like. Might be it's a bad question by and in itself, I don't know.

Comment: And besides, I've read the `seaborn` tutorial, it is written with great clarity and I really like it, which is partly why I want to learn this package thoroughly. But the `tsplot()` function is not covered in the tutorial and the link you gave is the api of the function, with all arguments and examples, but not much explanation. I read it before, and figured it's not the function I want.  I'll just keep the question open in case someone else might feel like downvoting it, or kindly enough to give an explanation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to do a regular plot, you should just use matplotlib. the closest thing I've found to a regular plot is the strip plot function from seaborn. I've actually just went back to just using matplotlib because of the customization. And I just use the seaborn styles to make my graphs look pretty.

here is the tutorial for seaborn:
http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial.html#tutorial

Comment: Thanks! `stripplot()` is meant for categorical data, but I want a time trend here, so not exactly what I want. And `tsplot` is not covered in the tutorial. I'll see if there is any option in `seaborn`, if not, I'll just go back to `matplotlib`.